# ftruncate on linux gives invalid arguments error

Tags: c++, linux

I have looked at `ftruncate` documentation from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate), as well as well from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/ftruncat.htm). In the case of IBM link, I implemented my `ftruncate` accordingly but it gives me `Invalid Arguments` error. Here is the code:

```
char const *path = "mozunit.txt";
int file_ = open(path, O_RDONLY, 0600);
int ftrunc_ = ftruncate(file_, 1);
cout<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
```

Why is it? I tried changing the second parameter in `ftruncate` but to no avail.

Comment: The variable is called `errno`, not `errorno`. Please post real code.

Comment: @interjay thanks, this is the real code. I had to type it here since emacs wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 10):

From the `ftruncate(2)` man page:

> ```
>   EBADF or EINVAL
>           fd is not open for writing.
> ```

Seeing as how you've opened the file as read-only...